# Reading in output as one line, not each word

Tags: bash, shell, unix

Basically what I am having trouble with is when I type: file *

I will get:

```
AdvDataStructures.text.ref: ASCII text
makefile:                   ASCII make commands text
makelib:                    ASCII English text
README.txt:                 ASCII Pascal program text
shell3_2016.sh:             ASCII text
shell3_2016.sh~:            ASCII text
smallTestDir:               directory
smallTestDir.text.out:      empty
smallTestDir.text.ref:      ASCII text
testarg0.text.ref:          ASCII text
testarg1.text.ref:          ASCII text
testbaddir.text.ref:        ASCII text
```

When I use

```
for i in `file *`
```

it reads in each word separated by space in for i. I need it to read in each line as: AdvDataStructures.text.ref: ASCII text ,so I can look through it for a pattern.

ALSO, I have no clue how to make it so when I read in the line, I somehow have to read in the amount of lines within the file that is called. Is there a way to like call the first word of the output so it knows to read in the file name?

Basically, an example of what I have to do is read in one line at a time (AdvDataStructures.text.ref: ASCII text), if a pattern finds a match in it (I know how to do this with egrep) it will the count the number of lines within the file(AdvDataStructures.text.ref)

Comment: This is why you [don't read lines with `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor) and why [Bash FAQ 001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) is how to do this properly. (Assuming you don't want to use a "better" tool like `awk`, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual way is to use  a `while read` loop:

```
file * | while read filename description; do
    filename=${filename%:} # remove : after filename
    ...
done
```

Comment: The first one worked, thank you very much! Just one more question, when doing this.. do you know how to split the file name away from the rest of the output?